# Magebto 1.9: Adding, Updating and Deleting products programatically returns wrong results

Tags: php, api, magento

In my app I am performing different actions like add, update and delete cart items programmatically, so the issue I am facing is when I add product into cart, update or delete product and then I run the code to fetch the latest cart items I am getting wrong results means getting the results of the previous step. e.g.

Add product into cart and after the get cart items I am getting items as empty array and on next call to get cart I am getting correct records

Update product quantity and after that get cart returns the previous quantity of item, so if I have a product and it's quantity in cart is 1 and I update the quantity I still get 1 in cart and in second call to get cart I am getting correct quantity.

same is for delete item from cart

Here is the code I am using

**1. Creating new Cart**

```
 $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $stroeId = $store->getId();
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
    $quote->setStoreId($stroeId)
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setIsMultiShipping(false)
                ->save();
    $quote->getBillingAddress();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote->collectTotals();
    $quote->save();
    $quoteId = $quote->getId();
```

**2. Add to Cart and immediately after the get Cart**

```
$products = array(array(
    'product_id' => $productId,
    'qty' => $qty,
    'options' => null,
    'super_attribute' => $custom_options,
    'bundle_option' => null,
    'bundle_option_qty' => null,
    'links' => null
));
$productMdl = Mage::getSingleton('myextension/product');
$result = $productMdl->add($quoteId, $products);
//This is the code for getting cart data
$apiMdl = Mage::getSingleton('myextension/api');
$result = $apiMdl->info($quoteId,Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$data = (array)$result;
```

I am calling the base magento API models in my models to use the default functionality of magento API for these actions.

Please suggest me any solution for this.

Thanks